# Prove or disprove. Is there a holomorphic function satisfying the following requirement.

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exists a holomorphic function $f(z)$ on $\left\{ z: |z|>2 \right\}$ such that $$\begin{align*}
f(z) = \frac{z^{2}}{z-1} && 2 < |z| <3
\end{align*}$$and $$\begin{align*}
f(z) =z^{3} && |z|>4
\end{align*}$$
I guess there doesn't exist such a holomorphic function. However, I don't know what I should use to deal with this problem. I guess it is an analytic continuation, but I'm not sure. Any help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the identity theorem?

Comment: @Mark I think yes. If I remember right, it says that if 2 holomorphic functions agree on the set with limit points, then 2 functions agree on the entire region, However, I don't know how to use it here.

Comment: Well, the sets $\{|z|>4\}$ and $\{2<|z|<3\}$ surely contain limit points, right? So use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill in the details for the approach suggested in Mark's comemnt: $z^3$ is defined on the domain $|z| > 2$ and agrees with $f(z)$ on the domain $|z| > 4$, so, by the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), as $f$ is defined on $|z|> 2$,  $f(z)=z^3$ on $|z|>2$, but this cannot be the case, if $f(z) = z^2/(z-1)$ for $2 < |z| < 3$, e.g., try $z = 5/2$.

Aside: you were along the right lines when you thought of analytic continuation, which in a sense lies at the heart of the identity theorem: when you extend two equal functions by analytic continuation over a connected domain, they cannot drift apart.